# I want to be able to update my software, how can I do this? Its asking for a password and I don't know where to get it from

Tags: updates

I want to be able to update my software, how can I do this?  Its asking for a password and I don't know where to get it from.

Comment: You do have a password, or else how do you logiin? When doing "sudo" or similar root operations, your password is just your password.

Comment: We can't help you remember the password, but you can reset it: [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Comment: You set your password when you created your account.

Answer (score 1):

You do have a password, or else how do you logiin? When doing "sudo" or similar root operations, the password is your password.